# How to pass data from a push segue in ios dev?

Tags: ios, segue

I apologise if this question has been asked before but I tried to search it for a couple of hours but can't find the answer.

I have an app which has a table view that lets the user to view their profile (I call it `ProfileTableView`), also, I have a push segue which lets them edit their profile (which I call `EditProfileTableView`). The profile has information like name, address, etc. I know how to pass data from the `ProfileTableView` to the `EditProfileTableView` via the prepareForSegue method. My problem is, how do you pass data from `EditProfileTableView` to `ProfileTableView`?

Comment: show some code plz. you could use delegate or complete block to put data back from `EditProfileTableView` to `ProfileTableView` if you popview or dismiss EditView

Comment: How are you going from Edit to Profile? If its an unwind segue, then you'd use the same `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: You may also keep these data in singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to pass data

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate pattern, or NSNotification. Or Both of this controllers can own same model object.

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` is the method which called right before your application is about to navigate to new `viewController` here you may check which `UIStoryboardSegue` is initialized and confirm which data to pass.like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueOfNewViewController"])
    {
        // Get a reference to the destination view controller
        DestinationViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
//by this you are having exactly the same refrence of viewController which is going to be displayed.
// now set objects as you must
destinationViewController.object = @“”;
    } }
```